# In Racket, is it possible to take a number in a list and break it up by each integer?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm sorry I couldn't figure out a better way to phrase my question. But hopefully this example makes more sense: I have a function that I'm writing, and in a part of it, I get results such as '(13). My question is, can I turn that into '(1 3)? I hope this is the right place to ask this since I haven't posted any code.

Comment: In math class, you learned that the number 13 is a short-hand representation of the polynomial 1 * 10^1 + 3 * 10^0. If you divide 13 by 10 and take both the quotient and remainder, you have the digits 1 and 3. Apply this recursively to numbers with more than two digits to split off the digits in succession, starting from the right.

Comment: I'll use modulo then, thanks!